# Add user in sso programmatically

Tags: 2010, secure-store

sorry if i misunderstood something.

I have a bunch of similar questions:

are there ways to create new SSS target application programmatically?

are there ways to add user(or user mapping) in SSS programmatically?

Comment: SSS, lol im a bit slow with abriviations ;)

Comment: oh, yeah, I'm sorry. "Add user in SSS programmatically" that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what you ask is essentially re-writing the Central Administration functionality. Managing Target Applications cannot be done from a content web application - it requires permissions to the configuration database.

If you want to automate the creation of target applications, I recommend starting with this Secure Store PowerShell script: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/a88f7b6e-9c9e-475f-afd1-c68c4ef3cc4a/